# MS ID client in MAUI: how to avoid UI to get access token silently after restart the App if I previously signed in

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal, maui

I am developing a cross-platform .NET 6 MAUI App for manage information and need to backup it to onedrive. It uses [Microsoft.Identity.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/) and [Microsoft.Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/) packages to authenticate, authorize and access to onedrive functionallity.

When I run **[the sample App](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2/blob/main/MauiApps.md)** from this **[MS Dev Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/authentication-in-dotnet-maui-apps-msal/)**, the 1st time it uses UI (system browser) to interact with the user and finally get the access token, the 2nd time as expected I can get the token silently, but whenever I restart the App, it requires UI again to get the token as if where the first time… This happens on windows 11, but not on Android...

How can I avoid the continuous use of UI to get the access token after restart the App, if previously already I signed in?

As far as I know, there is a token cache in **[MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview)**, but it appears to get flushed when I restart the App.

Thank you in advance

Comment: How exactly did you quit the app? Swipe-kill? You didn’t click sign out, right?

Comment: Thanks to your comment I could realize that it could be a browser extension (Norton Safe Web) that interferes to get tokens silently... I deactivated this browser plugin and the app worked ok on windows too... thank you for helping me...
Thanks to your comment I could realize that it could be a browser extension (Norton Safe Web) that interferes to get tokens silently... I deactivated this browser plugin and the app worked ok on windows too... thank you for helping me, Steve...

Comment: Excellent! Add that as Your Answer below. Then anyone else with similar problem will find answer more easily.

Comment: I am confused.... after a few intents, the problem reappered on windows (with Norton Safe Web plugin disabled)... :-(

Comment: I'm not familiar with MSAL, but maybe there is some parameter controlling how long the token is valid?

Comment: Dear ToolmakerSteve, I was able to figure out why this happened. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On desktop Apps, the tokens are in-memory, not persisted by default. If you close the app that acquired the tokens, the cache is lost. You have to persist this cache (serializing) to preserve the tokens...

[Token cache serialization in MSAL.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization?tabs=mobile)

"MSAL.NET provides an in-memory token cache by default. Serialization is provided by default for platforms where secure storage is available for a user as part of the platform: Universal Windows Platform (UWP), Xamarin.iOS, and Xamarin.Android.

...

In desktop applications, we recommend that you use the cross-platform token cache. MSAL.NET provides the cross-platform token cache in a separate library named Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal."

**Dec 11, 2022 - Edition:**
I checked again in repository of the sample and found that "[MAUI sample has moved](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-maui)"

Now, the new sample project seems to persist token cache on windows (as it did on android/ios)...

You can use this new project as reference to build an App that needs to get user's consent to access  a cloud API (Ej. on Microsoft Graph)...

Microsoft's Guys are hard working, it seems!

Comment: [Maui / Secure Storage / Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=windows) might be helpful, as a place to store (persist) the token securely.

Comment: Dear ToolmakerSteve... I finally decided to get Code Control, AccessToken, Refresh Token and ExpirationTime with an HTTP client and Embedded WebView.... so I maybe will store this critical information using this Secure Storage or maybe will store in SQLite/SQLChiper in an encrypted DB... Thank you for your help!